# C# регулирование доступа к папке

Tags: c#

Пишу программу для работы с текстовыми документами. Появилась идея создания пользователей в программе. Работать будет таким образом: создаётся пользователь (имя и пароль), создаётся папка которая будет названа в соответствии с именем пользователя, если пользователь выходит из программы, папка с его именем блокируется (или скрывается) до тех пор, пока пользователь не зайдёт в программу и не введёт верное имя и пароль. Хочу узнать, возможно ли как-то регулировать доступ к папке с помощью с#? Как её можно заблокировать или хотя бы скрыть?

Comment: А что в папке? Какие файлы?

Comment: Текстовые документики созданные через программу.

Comment: А какой уровень защиты данных предполагается? Чтобы "бухгалтер Тамара не открыла", или "опытный сисадмин Вася 3 дня мучался, и не смог", или "оперативный хакер Федя из ОБЭП всё перепробовал, но смог добыть из данных только строчку `oBLomAySya, TeBe eTo Ne VzlomaT'`"?

Comment: Если прямо ответить на ваш вопрос, то: возможно, но это очень сложно, и потребуются полные права доступа к диску, например прослойка между драйвером и системой, типа BitLocker. Или права доступа на уровне NTFS, но для этого у каждого пользователя должна быть своя учетка в системе, что вряд-ли вообще удобно. Исходя из этого, я предполагаю, что вы не планируете что-либо писать на C++ на низком уровне и заводить кучу пользователей в систему, поэтому пытаюсь выяснить, а какую именно задачу вам надо решить? Но лучше всего, если вы сами дополните свой вопрос.

Comment: Я просто хочу чтобы если пользователь не мог получить доступ к файлу не авторизовавшись в программе. Не обязательно чтобы всё было защищено самым лучшим образом, просто чтобы поверхностно нельзя было открыть папку созданную в программе без авторизации в программе. Я ещё предполагал, что реализовать это можно с помощью обычного архива. Тоесть, создавать в программе не папку, а архив. Это по сути легче реализовать?

Comment: Можете попробовать с архивом, да. А где будете хранить пароли? В архиве под паролем? А пароль от архива с паролями?

Comment: Нет, так как программа не для кого-то а чисто ради обучения то хранить буду в текстовом документе. Думал потом найти метод простого какого-то шифрования

Comment: Если ради обучения, то изучите вариант реализации с базой данных а не с файлами, например MS Access, база в `mdb` файле. Или любой другой SQL. А пароли в этом случае можно просто захешировать, например алгоритмом sha256. Такой подход даст вам больше полезных знаний и будет ближе к реальности, чем просто запуск архиватора с параметрами.